# Tinythread++: getting thread ID

Tags: c++, string, stl

This is how you get it printed to the terminal.

```
cout << "Current thread ID: " << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
```

Of course when there are multiple threads the output becomes interleaved and impossible to figure out. So I wanted to log each thread's output to its own file. But I need the thread ID to give a name to the file to send to `fopen()`. How to use iostream to save thread ID to a string?

Comment: I'm nitpicking, but this question is not really about multithreading, Tinythread++, nor getting a thread ID, it's about STL string formatting.  You really are more likely to get good, useful answers if you accurately describe your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use std::stringstream

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream s;
s << "File_Name:_" << this_thread::get_id();

std::ofstream file(s.str().c_str());
```